# Spring Framework's Validation is Not Working with JSR-303 Validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

My question is related to bean validation. Apparently SpringBoot comes with two different validation mechanisms, one `JSR-303` compilant (in `javax.validation` package) and the other provided by Spring framework (in `org.springframework.validation` package).

While it is easy to enforce `JSR-303` validation via `@Validated` and `@Valid` annotations, I couldn't find the proper way for Spring's ones.

Take the following `User` bean.

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    @Column
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @Username
    private String username;

    // [...]
}
```

Where `@Username` constraint is defined as follows. Basically, it's just a composition of `@Pattern` and `@Size` costraints.

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Documented
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9_]+")
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Size(max = 24, min = 3)
@Target(FIELD)
public @interface Username {
    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

`User` beans are stored in a repository named `UserRepository`, defined as follows.

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
}
```

To access the repository I wrote a service, shown below.

```java
@Transactional
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Validated
    public void create(@Valid User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Until now, things are pretty neat and everything works. With just a couple of annotations I've achieved everything.

Now, I have this other validator (not `JSR-303`).

```java
// [...]
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@Component
public class UniqueUsernameValidator implements Validator {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return User.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User) target;

        if (userRepository.count(where(usernameIsEqualTo(user.getUsername()))) > 0) {
            errors.rejectValue("username", "username.exists");
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to have it enforced via the same `@Validated` and `@Valid` annotations but until now I've been unlucky. I guess it is definitely possible given that the documentation of the class `org.springframework.validation.Validator` says

> This interface is totally divorced from any infrastructure or context; that is to say it is not coupled to validating only objects in the web tier, the data-access tier, or the whatever-tier. As such it is amenable to being used in **any layer of an application**, and supports the encapsulation of validation logic as a first-class citizen in its own right.

Comment: `@Validated` should be present at the type level on `UserService`.

Comment: Executing a database query as part of validation is probably not the best approach.  Better yet would be to handle the constraint violation exception during the insert, and return that to the client.

Comment: I'm developing a REST API and and `SQLException` wouldn't give me the information I need to present the error to the client. Also, this is a simple example, unfortunately there will be other validations that require a fairly complex query to preserve integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Valid` is a JSR-303 bean validation annotation, and it won't call your `UniqueUsernameValidator` Spring Validator.

If you want to do that in your service, you need to invoke it manually:

```
public void create(@Valid User user) {
    Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(user, "user");

    // Validator component has been previously injected into the service.
    uniqueUsernameValidator.validate(user, errors); 
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(errors.toString());
    }

    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: I have another question, though. What's the use for the `Validator#supports()` method if in the end we invoke `Validator#validate()` by hand? To me the presence of `Validator#supports()` method is indication of some automatic behavior, maybe annotation driven.

Comment: Also, it's true that `@Valid` is part of JSR-303 (as it belongs to the package `javax.validation`), but `@Validated` is in the package `org.springframework.validation.annotation` as the `Validator` interface. The whole thing makes little sense to me.